# About firebase onDiconnect() and pricing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Little question about liseners and firebase in general.

I know that with the free spark programm a max of 100 simultaneous listeners connected to the firebase project are allowed, as far as I understand.

I face the little problem that I use multiple `.onDiconnect` calls which work simultanously in my app.

Therefore my question would be if this `.onDiconnect` is considered to be a listener and also if it counts towards those 100 listeners that are allowed before I need to pay, each one individual counting of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with the free spark programm a max of 100 simultaneous listeners connected to the firebase project are allowed

This is not how it works. On the Spark plan there can be 100 concurrent **clients** listening. Each client can have as many listeners as it wants.

So having multiple (`onDisconnect` or other) listeners on a single client does not affect how many clients can connect to the servers at the same tie.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find, `onDisconnect` is not a listener and should not affect that limit, but rather creates an object that is handed to the server that will be processed when the client is disconnected.

You can read about it in the following articles:

- [Firebase Realtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect)
- [Google Play](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect)
- [Firebase Google Play](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/OnDisconnect)